# BroadcastChannel sometime not listening at useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am facing a problem that the broadcast channel is not listening sometime in `useEffect`. There is some list and upon clicking individual item, the broadcast postmessage should be emitting message to the listener of another file. Sometime it's working but for some reason, it's not receiving that event.

This snippet is located at index.js. Upon changes happened in dependencies, I am getting debug message all the time however it's not going inside `onMessage`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const messageBus = new BroadcastChannel('channelABC');
    console.debug("ITS COMING HERE ALL THE TIME");
    const onMessage = ({ data: message }) => {
      if (message.type === 'ABCFired') {
        showABC(message);
      }
    };

    messageBus.addEventListener('message', onMessage);

    return () => {
      messageBus.removeEventListener('message', onMessage);
      messageBus.close();
    };

  }, [dependencies]);
```

This is another file where message is being emitted.

```
const onRowClicked = index => {
    setId(oldId => {
          if (oldId !== index) {
            console.debug("ITS ALSO WORKING");
            messageBus.postMessage({ type: 'ABCFired', message });
            return index;
          }
          else {
            return null;
          }
        });
  };
```

Comment: How are you messageBus in the other file if it's defined within the useEffect?

Answer (score 0):

I am searching through the same answer right now. I have found that maybe when  the broadcast channel shoots a message, the component gets unmount and the event listener is removed.

So by the time the message is fired, there is no listener.

Make a console statement in return function of use effect called

```
console.log('unmount)
```

You already have a console in onRowClicked, so check when you fire, onRowClicked, do you get unmount after that or something.

**Quickfix**
Remove the dependency from use Effect. In your case you want to enable eventListner once the app starts, I think.